# Laravel Polymorphic Relation not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, polymorphism, relationship

trying to get some polymorphic relations working in laravel 4.

I have a CoreUserAccount table that looks like so:

> core_user_account:
>
> id
>
> profile_id
>
> other columns

I then have 2 other tables core_user_client_profile and core_user_consultant_profile. They both have id fields.

i am trying to link them like so:

In the CoreUserAccount model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

And in both the other tables i have:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->morphOne('CoreUserAccount', 'profile');
}
```

But i don't seem to be able to get any of the profile data through the user object. Any ideas?

Cheers

**EDIT**

Here is my core_user_account table:

[image: core_user_account]

And here are my 2 different profile type tables core_user_client_profile and core_user_consultant_profile:

[image: Consultant]

[image: Client]

Here is my model for core_user_account:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class CoreUserAccount
    extends Eloquent
    implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{
    protected $table = 'core_user_account';
    protected $hidden = array('password');
    protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');

    public function profileType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserProfileType');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserAddress', 'user_account_id', 'id');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getRememberToken() {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value) {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName() {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
}
```

And my core_user_client_profile model:

```
class CoreUserClientProfile
    extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'core_user_client_profile';

    public function profileLanguage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserProfileLanguages');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('CoreUserAccount', 'profile',null,'profile_id',null);
    }
}
```

And my core_user_consultant_profile model:

```
class CoreUserConsultantProfile
    extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'core_user_consultant_profile';

    public function profileLanguage()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserProfileLanguages', 'consultant_profile_id', 'id');
    }

    public function qualifications()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserConsultantQualifications', 'profile_id', 'id');
    }

    public function registration()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserConsultantRegistrations', 'profile_id', 'id');
    }

    public function specialities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('CoreUserConsultantProfileSpeciality', 'profile_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('CoreUserAccount', 'profile');
    }
}
```

I have read the document pointed out in the comments below and understand i seem to have to have a type column in my DB. But what data needs to be stored here? does it automatically get stored or do i have to store it?

Cheers

Comment: Do you have profile_id and profile_type columns in core_user_account table ? Could you paste your all model and table structure?

Comment: Hi Pawel.  I will be able to post it all tomorrow when I'm back at work. I don't have a profile type column though? What is it for and why do I need it?  Cheers

Comment: Look on this doc http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

 This is what allows the ORM to determine which type of owning model to return when accessing the imageable relation.

Comment: I have updated my question Pawel. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have to have profile_type, and profile_id columns. In profile_type will be stored values: 'CoreUserConsultantProfile' or 'CoreUserClientProfile'. This fields will be populated automaticlly when you save data.

This is example how save data in polymorph relation.

```
$profile = CoreUserConsultantProfile::find(1);
$account = new CoreUserAccount();

$profile->profile()->save($account);
```

So now, profile_id=1, and profile_type = 'CoreUserConsultantProfile'